# Alternate or better way to attach and apply time/date to user submitted data and convert to specified time zones

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, timezone

Currently the way I'm attaching, storing and converting time/date with user posts/uploads/registration times etc is by setting the default time zone to UTC and fetching the time stamp with PHP's `time()` when processing.

I then store the data with each row submitted in the database (`int(11)`) and then when I display their posts/uploads etc I do a query where I bring the attached time stamp with it and convert it according to their specified time zone and make it readable by putting into a date format.

*Note that `$timezone` and `$date_format` have been chosen from their profile settings upon creating an account.*

**Storing data**

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $time_stamp = time();

    // MySQL injection protection here...
    // Store data here...

?>
```

**Retrieving data**

```
<?php

    // MySQL query here....

    $post_time = $row['time_stamp'];

    $post_dt_zone = new DateTimeZone($timezone);

    $time_from_post = date('r', $post_time);

    $post_d_time = new DateTime($time_from_post);

    $post_d_time->setTimeZone($post_dt_zone);

    $time_from_post = $post_d_time->format($date_format);

?>
```

Now my question is, is this a good method? Are there alternatives which are more commonly used or will I come across problems in the future if I try to update anything?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the circumstance. Judging by the name of your variables you're logging the time a post was made. You can use the php `time()` method, or you can use the MySQL method.

MySQL method: You create a table (or edit the current one) with the time posted field `'time_posted'` as:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
id int NOT NULL,
time_posted datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

The only thing that changes when you insert a new row, is that you no longer need to insert a timestamp (or date), this will be done automatically by MySQL.

However you should know that using `NOW()` will store the date/time in the following format: `2011-12-10 12:51:23.212`
. So if this is how you want your date to be displayed then this could be a method you can use. You can also use `CURDATE()` and `CURTIME()` which show (separately) the date and time respectively.

However if you want to display the date/time in a different format, you would need to to use `strtotime()` or `mktime()` to retrieve the timestamp of the date/time posted, and then use your preferred method to display it in the way that you want. If this is the case, I think your current method is best.

Comment: I get #1067 - Invalid default value for 'time_posted'